# ML.net. What is the difference between mlContext.Transforms.Text.FeaturizeText and mlContext.Transforms.Categorical.OneHotEncoding methods?

Tags: c#, ml.net

I came accross to classification problem where FeaturizeText method was used to convert some text value to numeric vector.For the same purpose in regression problem OneHotEncoding method was used. So what is the difference??? Thanks in advance.
I couldn't find anything helpful with Microsoft's documentation.

Answer (score 9):

OneHotVectorizer is a deprecated API. Maybe you can use OneHotEncoding.
Based on the ML.NET API reference:

[FeaturizeText](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.ml.textcatalog.featurizetext?view=ml-dotnet#Microsoft_ML_TextCatalog_FeaturizeText_Microsoft_ML_TransformsCatalog_TextTransforms_System_String_System_String_) - Transform text into a float array that represents counts of n-grams and char-grams.
[OneHotEncoding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.ml.transforms.onehotencodingtransformer?view=ml-dotnet)- Converts the categorical value into an indicator array by building a dictionary of categories based on the data and using the id in the dictionary as the index in the array.

Basically, if you have categorical data (distinct finite values), like days of the week, brands of cars, anything that expresses categories, you'd want to use OneHotEncoding, and just convert them into numbers. Machine learning algorithms work on numbers, so text/images etc. needs to be converted to numbers.

If you have free form text, and are trying to make sense of something on it: like what is the overall sentiment, or what is the topic on this body of text, etc. you'd want to use FeaturizeText

Examplesof usage:

[FeaturizeText](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.ml.textcatalog.featurizetext?view=ml-dotnet#Microsoft_ML_TextCatalog_FeaturizeText_Microsoft_ML_TransformsCatalog_TextTransforms_System_String_System_String_)
[OneHotEncoding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.ml.categoricalcatalog.onehotencoding?view=ml-dotnet#Microsoft_ML_CategoricalCatalog_OneHotEncoding_Microsoft_ML_TransformsCatalog_CategoricalTransforms_Microsoft_ML_InputOutputColumnPair___Microsoft_ML_Transforms_OneHotEncodingEstimator_OutputKind_System_Int32_Microsoft_ML_Transforms_ValueToKeyMappingEstimator_KeyOrdinality_Microsoft_ML_IDataView_)

Comment: I don't understand why this answer is not yet upvoted?